# Create Button at runtime and save it permanently in c#

Tags: c#, button

I have this code to create a button:

```
    private void CreateButton(){
Button createButton = new Button();

// Set Button properties
createButton.Height = 40;
createButton.Width = 300;
createButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
createButton.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
createButton.Location = new Point(20, 150);
createButton.Text = "I am Button";
createButton.Name = "Button";
createButton.Font = new Font("Georgia", 16);
createButton.Click += new EventHandler(create_Button_Click);

this.Controls.Add(createButton);            
    }
    private void create_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     MessageBox.Show("button is clicked");
    }
```

and i want to save it permanently in the project. what is the best way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "save it permanently in the project" ?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- I guess yess, he wants that whenever he launches the application, the newly created button should be there.